# How is the best way to overcome bad / inconsistent data in an event-store?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Event stores are supposed to be Add only, you never delete or edit data.

In my case, we didn't disallow some mid-stream changes that were made by a user, and the data is "bad" / inconsistent... in that they changed a domain name for google docs that we were provisioning mid-stream...

I can reprovision from the event store, but that data is broken.

Should I create a mutator of some kind that as it pulls the data from the event store, fix it up?

I need some ideas here!

Comment: If you need a quick answer, this question, and variants of it have been discussed at length on the DDD/CQRS mailing list

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the "bad" data were correct back then?

I suggest you fix this by not touching the events, but update the provisioning service to handle the broken domain names. That could be a component which knows how to fix a domain name or a url: You send a resource in and get a corrected version in return. Unknown resources could be returned as is.